# Why this is giving an error?

Tags: math-mode, errors

To write the following equation, I am writing my code as

```
$\textbf{\mu}$ (in the text or paragraph)
```

why it is giving an error?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // You are in math mode. Best will be you post code, which we can copy and it will compile. Thank you

Comment: If I run your example, the error I get is "Undefined control sequence `\textbf`", because I don't use LaTeX and this control sequence is defined in LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

`\mu` is math-mode macro. `\textbf` is a text-mode macro that expects its argument to be in text mode.

The fix? Depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish, either load the `bm` (short for "bold math") package and write `$\bm{\mu}$` or write `\textbf{\textmu}` (in text mode).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$\mu$ $\bm{\mu}$ \textmu{} \textbf{\textmu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working